# PMP application

Tags: pmp

I am in the process of writing my PMP application. I am a Program Manager at my work, however, I manage multiple similar projects in a year.

Can I bundle up all similar projects and document them ONCE in the application or should write them separately?

Also, I am concerned if this a flag because they are "similar" projects for different customers.

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: It is not possible for SE to provide an authoritative answer to this question; you'd have to ask PMI that question.

Answer (score 1):

Review page 8 of the handbook. In it, they talk about overlapping projects. The implication of the rules will answer your questions. Don't read what you want to read. Read what's there.